# How to add logs to a file/blob in an azure container with basicConfig

Tags: python, azure, logging

I want to save the logs into a file/blob in a specific folder of an azure container using **python.**

I've used this code;

```
today = date.today()

logging.basicConfig(filename='http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/cloudops-resources/logs/{}_logs.log'.format(today),
                filemode='a',
                format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(message)s',
                datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                level=logging.INFO,
                force=True)
```

But it gives an error.

> Executed 'Functions.BlobTrigger' (Failed, Id=8863e10e-2cb6-4a32-8f3a-2486823740cb, Duration=30ms)
> [2023-04-19T11:28:58.348Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.BlobTrigger. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
> Exception: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\Automization of Invoice Compare\Service Projects-1\Application Cloud\Customers\InvoiceCompare\http:\127.0.0.1:10000\devstoreaccount1\cloudops-resources\logs\2023-04-19_logs.log'
> Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 452, in _handle__invocation_request
> call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(
> File "C:\Users\Asu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
> result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
> File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 718, in *run_sync_func
> return ExtensionManager.get_sync_invocation_wrapper(context,
> File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.9/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\extension.py", line 215, in *raw_invocation_wrapper
> result = function(**args)
> File "D:\Automization of Invoice Compare\Service Projects-1\Application Cloud\Customers\InvoiceCompare\BlobTrigger_*init**.py", line
> 20, in main
> logging.basicConfig(filename='http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1/cloudops-resources/logs/{}*logs.log'.format(today),
> File "C:\Users\Asu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\logging_*init**.py", line 2003, in basicConfig
> h = FileHandler(filename, mode,
> File "C:\Users\Asu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\logging_*init**.py", line 1146, in **init**
> StreamHandler.**init**(self, self.*open())
> File "C:\Users\Asu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\logging_*init**.py", line 1175, in _open
> return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding,

Can someone please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

> How to add logs to a file/blob in an azure container with basicConfig

Using `basicConfig` you can add a log file to storage account, but you are wrong in sending URL in place of **PATH** of the log File and this is working if i am giving local path too.

Below is the code(updated your code):

```
import logging
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

c = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwik2;AccountKey=PVggwes02w==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net'
bsc = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(c)
cn = "emocon"
bn = "emolog"
cc = bsc.get_container_client(cn)
cb = cc.get_blob_client(bn)
logging.info("Hello Rithwik")
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                    format="%(asctime)s [%(name)s] %(message)s",
                    handlers=[logging.StreamHandler(),
                              logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler("emolog.log")])
with open("emolog.log", "rb") as d:
    cb.upload_blob(d, overwrite=True)
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

So you can integrate the above code into your function app.

Comment: I tried it, the file is created but it is empty.(btw I'm trying this with azure storage explorer.)

Comment: Oh, but it wasn't empty for me